# To each element (string) of the list1 add an element from the list2 in Python

Tags: python, list

### There are two lists:

```
list1  = ["shirts","jeans"]

list2 = ["white","red","yellow"]
```

---

From these two lists I want to make the third one:

```
list3 = ["white shirts","red shirts","yellow shirts","white jeans","red jeans", "yellow jeans"]
```

---

So that for each element (string) of **list 1** to be added an element from the **list 2**.

I've got the following code:

```
my_list1 = ['shirts', 'jeans']
string = ' red'
my_new_list1 = [x + string for x in my_list1]
print (my_new_list1)

my_list2 = ['shirts', 'jeans']
string = ' white'
my_new_list2 = [x + string for x in my_list2]
print (my_new_list2)

my_list3 = ['shirts', 'jeans']
string = ' yellow'
my_new_list3 = [x + string for x in my_list3]
print (my_new_list3)
```

but this piece of code isn't quite exactly whats needed. moreover, its needed that list 1 & list 2 were taken from list1.txt & list2.txt, and the resulting list 3 to be exported to list3.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to do something like this:

```
l1 = ['shirts', 'jeans']
l2 = ['white', 'red', 'yellow']
l3 = [j + " " + i for i in l1 for j in l2]

print(l3)
```

So the output will be:

```
['white shirts', 'red shirts', 'yellow shirts', 'white jeans','red jeans', 'yellow jeans']
```

Edited:

So, with .txt files I would do this:

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = pd.read_csv('list1.txt', header = None).values.flatten()
l2 = pd.read_csv('list2.txt', header = None).values.flatten()
l3 = [j + " " + i for i in l1 for j in l2]

with open('list3.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in l3:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works great. How do I modify this if the lists are text files, like l1.txt, l2.txt with one string per line in them? And the output to export in l3.txt (also one string per line)?

Comment: @Norrven, I edited my answer, If you think it helped please mark it as correct :D

Comment: Diana Ayala, your answer is absolutely accurate and works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

If the order is not important, you can do:

```py
from itertools import product 

l1 = ["shirts", "jeans"]
l2 = ["white", "red", "yellow"]

result = [' '.join(a) for a in product(l2, l1)]
```

```
['white shirts',
 'white jeans',
 'red shirts',
 'red jeans',
 'yellow shirts',
 'yellow jeans']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# your code goes here
list1 = ['shirts','jeans']
list2 = ['white','red','yellow']
result = ['{} {}'.format(color, cloth) for cloth in list1 for color in list2 ]
print(result)
```

output

```
['white shirts', 'red shirts', 'yellow shirts', 'white jeans', 'red jeans', 'yellow jeans']
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
list3 = [y + " " + x for y in list1 for x in list2]
```

Should result be sorted like that: `list3 = ["white shirts","red shirts","yellow shirts","white jeans","red jeans", "yellow jeans"]`?

Comment: Thank you! There is no need to sort the result, just add a string to a string in whatever way. But the 2 lists are quite long (hundreds of strings), so I have them in txt files (one string per line). Is there an easy way to modify this so that the lists were taken from list1.txt & list2.txt and the output to be exported to the resulting list3.txt (also one string per line)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a list comprehension to get `list3`

```
list3 =   ["{} {}".format(y,x) for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

output

```
     ['white shirts',
 'red shirts',
 'yellow shirts',
 'white jeans',
 'red jeans',
 'yellow jeans']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you were not as clear as expected, so the solution i'll post here might be incorrect. For your algorithm to work with the files you've mentioned, the following code should do:

```
with open('list1.txt') as f:
    list1 = f.read().splitlines()
with open('list2.txt') as f:
    list2 = f.read().splitlines()
# my_list1 = ['shirts', 'jeans']
list3 = []
for i in range(len(list2)):
    list3.append(list2[i] +' '+ list1[i])
print(list3)
```